# Transform Bitmap or ImageView at specific coordinates

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, coordinates, transform

I am trying to transform bitmap and imageview by dragging points to specific coordinates [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK7bA.png)  this is drawing app. Which is the best way to make it ? Should i use OpenGL ? Thank You

**EDIT:**  I fixed by using canvas.drawBitmapMesh thank you all for your help i really appreciate it .

Comment: simple Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix,  Paint) will do the trick, all you need is to compute the correct Matrix

Comment: which matrix method to use for it ? Where can i read more about this issue

Comment: read carefully Matrix documentation

Comment: from http://developer.android.com/ ?

Comment: yes,  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating second mutable bitmap like this

```
Bitmap originalBitmap;
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b)
```

Then you can draw original bitmap on top of new bitmap applying transformations. See [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) API for more details.

For example use the following method:

```
c.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)
```

**Update**

Regarding use of Matrix, it's just a guess, you can try method mapPoints(float[] src, float[] dest). I also did a quick search on Google and found [web page](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.Matrix) with examples. Have a look.

**Update 2**

Dardan was able to achieve his goal with the following method:

```
drawBitmapMesh(Bitmap bitmap, int meshWidth, int meshHeight, float[] verts, int vertOffset, int[] colors, int colorOffset, Paint paint);
```

Method description:

> Draw the bitmap through the mesh, where mesh vertices are evenly
>   distributed across the bitmap. There are meshWidth+1 vertices across,
>   and meshHeight+1 vertices down. The verts array is accessed in
>   row-major order, so that the first meshWidth+1 vertices are
>   distributed across the top of the bitmap from left to right. A more
>   general version of this method is drawVertices().

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help me i'll try it now. :)

Comment: fixed by using canvas.drawBitmapMesh